# C# Code for focus to the next cells in a data gridview when the user press enter after fill the current cell

Tags: c#

My Current code is as bellow. It is working fine for readonly= true but when I am inserting the value then it is focusing to the same cell no of the bellow rows. Please advice me regarding this.

MY CODE:

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
            {
                int col = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
                int row = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            if (col < dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1)
            {
                col++;
            }
            else
            {
                col = 0;
                row++;
            }

            if (row == dataGridView1.RowCount)
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add();

            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[col, row];
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to achieve the same functionality as you would have when pressing `TAB`?